# When it comes to + N / V ing

Tags: word-choice

My question is:

> When it comes to (A): choosing (B): choose (C): choice

The answer is (A), but I don't understand why I can't choose (C)?

I think that after "When it comes to" both N or V-ing can be used.

Comment: You need an action noun in the sentence. A gerund is the best choice in such a case.  "When it comes to (A): *choosing* "-- OTOH, *choose* is a verb, not a noun; *choice* is a noun but shows no action. HTH.

Comment: _When it comes to choice, you can't go wrong shopping at Baumgardner's Market_.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that this is a pedagogical exercise in which your teacher wants you to learn some lesson in the syntax of gerunds.  Unfortunately for the both of you, English idiom is considerably more flexible than this stock example.  Consider the following examples from 1. *[The Parliamentary Debates (Hansard)](https://books.google.com/books?id=z2UdAQAAMAAJ&q=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choose%22&dq=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choose%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMIxqvzl_K0yAIVATg-Ch25DAf4)* 1977 and 2. *[How to Catch a Fish](https://books.google.com/books?id=dsW4BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA27&dq=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choose%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAGoVChMI7qvFsvS0yAIVBSweCh3STAUa#v=onepage&q=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choose%22&f=false)* by Ross Waters (1964)

1. > We have all seen over a considerable number of years the tremendous
   >   temptations which come to Prime Ministers **when it comes to choose**
   >   dates for elections.
2. > These are little clues that you must not overlook **when it comes to
   >   choose** your bait.

In these cases, the phrase means and is often replaced by "when it comes time to choose."

I can think of two instances in which (C) will be acceptable.  The first is when you're talking about choice as an abstraction and not about a particular choice, like the one you confront at a restaurant between French dressing and Russian dressing for your salad.  For example, from *[The Myth of Choice: Personal Responsibility in a World of Limits](https://books.google.com/books?id=iMoIg2EXsr4C&pg=PA3&dq=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBGoVChMIlZ3WhPW0yAIVxHo-Ch1N_gP-#v=onepage&q=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choice%22&f=false)*
by Kent Greenfield:

> Also consider the role of power and authority **when it comes to
>   choice**.

This is choice in a broad sense.  But *choice* can also be a shorthand for a more restricted sense, e.g., "choice" as the right of a woman to choose whether to carry her pregnancy to term or "choice" as the claim of the benighted that people make a conscious choice for their sexual orientation.  From *[Homosexual Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kibhb6kDhK0C&pg=PA1&dq=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCDgKahUKEwjxjpz997TIAhXGgj4KHUWRBOo#v=onepage&q=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choice%22&f=false)* by Ken Smith:

> **When it comes to choice**, however, I have counseled with many
>   homosexual individuals and not one says that they would choose that
>   particular stand if they had a choice.

The second instance which makes (C) acceptable is the terms of art in contract law, "choice of law" and "choice of court."  Contracts may specify which jurisdiction's law will govern a dispute and which jurisdiction's legal system will adjudicate a dispute.  (These two need not be the same, and each may differ from the jurisdiction in which the contracting parties reside.)  Thus from 1. *[Japanese and European Private International Law in Comparative Perspective](https://books.google.com/books?id=nozPlJIkyDsC&pg=PA112&dq=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAGoVChMIlPCfofm0yAIVihc-Ch21ygfH#v=onepage&q=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choice%22&f=false)* by J. Basedow and H Baum and 2. *[Rome I Regulation: The Law Applicable to Contractual Obligations in Europe](https://books.google.com/books?id=G0WM7H8SP5wC&pg=PA289&dq=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAmoVChMIlPCfofm0yAIVihc-Ch21ygfH#v=onepage&q=%22when%20it%20comes%20to%20choice%22&f=false)* by F. Ferrari and S. Leible:

1. > Parties may very well favor a "neutral court" **when it comes to
   >   choice** of court.
2. > One can only observe the irony of the position **when it comes to
   >   choice** of law in contract.